# How do I click a button in a form using Selenium and Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a Python program that periodically checks a website for a specific update.  The site is secured and multiple clicks are required to get to the page that I want to monitor.  Unfortunately, I am stuck trying to figure out how to click a specific button.  Here is the button code:

```
<input type="button" class="bluebutton" name="manageAptm" value="Manage Interview Appointment" onclick="javascript:programAction('existingApplication', '0');">
```

I have tried numerous ways to access the button and always get "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:" error.  The obvious approach to access the button is XPath and using the Chrome X-Path Helper tool, I get the following:

```
/html/body/form/table[@class='appgridbg mainContent']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@class='maincontainer']/div[@class='appcontent'][1]/table[@class='colorgrid']/tbody/tr[@class='gridItem']/td[6]/input[@class='bluebutton']
```

If I include the above as follows:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table[@class='appgridbg mainContent']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[@class='maincontainer']/div[@class='appcontent'][1]/table[@class='colorgrid']/tbody/tr[@class='gridItem']/td[6]/input[@class='bluebutton']").submit()
```

I still get the NoSuchElementException error.

I am new to selenium and so there could be something obvious that I am missing; however, after much Googling, I have not found an obvious solution.

On another note, I have also tried find_element_by_name('manageAptm') and find_element_by_class_name('bluebutton') and both give the same error.

Can someone advise on how I can effectively click this button with Selenium?

Thank you!

Comment: The `find_element_by_name` you tried looks promising to me. Try to use it with [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow your attempts and the @har07's comment, the `find_element_by_name('manageAptm')` should work, but the element might not be immediately available and you may need to [wait for it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
manageAppointment = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "manageAptm")))
manageAppointment.click()
```

Also, check if the element is inside an `iframe` or not. If yes, you would need to switch into the context of it and only then issue the "find" command:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_name_or_id")
driver.find_element_by_name('manageAptm').click()
```