# How do I click a Javascript button on a webpage using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I know this question has been asked a million times here and I have tried them all, I still can't get my python code to click a button!

So here's the result of the inspect element of said button:
`<input value="New Quote" class="btn" name="new_quote_wizard" title="New Quote" type="button" onclick="if (window.invokeOnClickJS_00bC0000001TjBl) window.invokeOnClickJS_00bC0000001TjBl(this); else if (parent.window.invokeOnClickJS_00bC0000001TjBl) parent.window.invokeOnClickJS_00bC0000001TjBl(this); return false">`

I've tried this:

```
browser.find_element_by_name('New Quote').click()
```

but it returns with this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="New Quote"]

What else can I do to click this one button?

Comment: *a million times* ... *I have tried them all* - pretty bold statement, since you are only giving one example you tried. ;-) But maybe you should not search for `New Quote`, which is the `value`, but rather for `new_quote_wizard`, which is the `name`.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianKönig! But unfortunately, I've tried that too and it also fails with a similar error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="new_quote_wizard"]

I've also tried the browser.findElementByXpath("//input[@value='New Quote'][@title='New Quote']").click();
And for that it says it doesn't recognise the xpath command

Comment: Is the tag is inside any frame or iframe?

Comment: I don't think so, how can I be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys - I got it working through another stackoverflow question here: [How do I click a button in a form using Selenium and Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928363/how-do-i-click-a-button-in-a-form-using-selenium-and-python-2-7)

So basically, I had to wait for the element!

I added these lines to my code:

> `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
>   newQuote = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "new_quote_wizard")))
>   newQuote.click()`

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like problem is in the selecting element by name providing value. Try this instead:

```
browser.find_element_by_name('new_quote_wizard').click()
```

Comment: Thanks @peregrino! But I've tried that, too, and it comes up with the same error : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="new_quote_wizard"]